# Pandas: Iterate through columns index/labels and group the ones that starts with the same strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multiple-columns

I want to group the column index/labels that starts with the same str, but I'cant use str.startswith() because it would be a very long list if I'd have to write every single prefix and than group.

So I want to iterate through every column's prefix (in format Q[0-9]) and group all similar ones together.

example with one prefix:

**Q1EXAMPLE Q1EXAMPLE1 Q2EXAMPLE2 Q2EXAMPLE3**

```
f1 = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Q1')]

df[f1]
```

Comment: Is there a regular expression with one or more match groups from which you can extract a group identifier from each column name?

Comment: I guess 'Q[0-9]'  @SteeleFarnsworth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To select the columns that start with regex pattern `Q[0-9]`, you can use [`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `regex=` parameter, as follows:

```
df2 = df.filter(regex=r'^Q[0-9]')
```

Regex meta-character `^` indicates matching start of text (column label)

2. Then, to create a lookup table (in form of a Python dictionary) to lookup results of every Qx, you can use the dict comprehension to iterate through the Pandas GroupBy objects of (groups of) column label prefixes by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `axis=1` on the column label prefixes, as follows:

```
Q_dict = {col_prefix: df_i for col_prefix, df_i in df2.groupby(df2.columns.str[:2], axis=1)}
```

**Demo**

1. Selection of relevant columns:

```
data = {'Col_1': ['a1', 'b1'],
 'Q1EXAMPLE': ['a2', 'b2'],
 'T1Q1': ['a3', 'b3'],
 'Q1EXAMPLE1': ['a4', 'b4'],
 'T1_Q9': ['a5', 'b5'],
 'Q2EXAMPLE2': ['a6', 'b6'],
 'T2EXAMPLE2': ['a7', 'b7'],
 'Q2EXAMPLE3': ['a8', 'b8'],
 'Col_n': ['a9', 'b9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

  Col_1 Q1EXAMPLE T1Q1 Q1EXAMPLE1 T1_Q9 Q2EXAMPLE2 T2EXAMPLE2 Q2EXAMPLE3 Col_n
0    a1        a2   a3         a4    a5         a6         a7         a8    a9
1    b1        b2   b3         b4    b5         b6         b7         b8    b9

df2 = df.filter(regex=r'^Q[0-9]')

print(df2)

  Q1EXAMPLE Q1EXAMPLE1 Q2EXAMPLE2 Q2EXAMPLE3
0        a2         a4         a6         a8
1        b2         b4         b6         b8
```

2. Use `Q_dict` to access the subset of columns starting with a particular prefix:

```
print(Q_dict['Q2'])

    Q2EXAMPLE2  Q2EXAMPLE3
0   a6          a8
1   b6          b8


print(Q_dict['Q1'])

    Q1EXAMPLE   Q1EXAMPLE1
0   a2          a4
1   b2          b4
```

Comment: I think the code: df.groupby(df.columns.str[:2], axis=1) solves my problem, but I'm getting an error about the lentgh of the df

Comment: @CarolVieira  As seen from your tried codes, you are not doing dataframe grouping as used in GroupBy, you just want to select the columns of those names, right ?

Comment: @CarolVieira  df.groupby is for grouping data elements within columns, not by grouping/selecting by column labels.  So, what do you want ?  group the data elements or the column labels ?

Comment: I think if I use 'df.filter()' I will end it up with the same problem as with the 'starswith()' thing. I can't select the matches to group in other dataframe

Comment: I want to group the column labels and bring all their respected elements to create others dataframes.]

Comment: each created dataframe must have all columns with the same first two characters in their names

Comment: @CarolVieira  Then you just use e.g.  `df_out = df.filter(regex=r'^Q[0-9]').copy()`  to create a new dataframe `df_out`

Comment: @CarolVieira  I have put the code in my edit above.  See whether this is what you need.

Comment: @SeanBean YAS! this code df_out = df.filter(regex=r'^Q[0-9]').copy() help select everything that I need indeed :)))but how can I match the individual differences and export that to a dataset?

Comment: @CarolVieira  What do you mean by 'individual differences' ?

Comment: @CarolVieira  What format of dataset you want to export to ?   CSV, Excel ?

Comment: I have the columns: Q1something, Q1something2, Q2something, Q2something2.

Comment: I want to group all the Q1something columns and in another dataset all the Q2something columns

Answer (score 0):

```py
grouped = df.groupby(df.columns.str[:2], axis=1)
```

Will group the columns by the first two characters of the name of the column.

Comment: I'm getting this error "ValueError: Item wrong length 210 instead of 511"

Comment: my df has 511 rows!

Comment: I can't guess why this is wrong without seeing the dataframe and exactly what code you ran.

Comment: I guess groupby can't help me because I'm trying to select these columns, find the matches and create separate dataframes! Not grouping the data within the same dataframe

Comment: the `.groupby` method creates a DataFrameGroupedBy. Iterating over it would then give you the individual, separate DataFrames according to each match.